# Alinhar imagem a direita do texto em coluna

Tags: html, css

Tenho uma seção, e a ideia é que o texto esteja a esquerda e a imagem a direita, juntos.
A imagem fica abaixo do texto, eu preciso que ela fique a direita e alinhada com o texto

```
<!-- Recompensas --><br><br>
<section class="recompensas-section">
    <div class="row align-items-center">

        <div class="col-md-6">
                  <h2 class="recompensas-title">
                Ajude e ganhe recompensas
            </h2>
            <p class="recompensas-description">
                Aproveite descontos e promoções exclusivas oferecidas pelos nossos parceiros,
                e use suas moedas para vivenciar experiências e trocar por brindes incríveis.
            </p>
            <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                <img src="images/Recompensas (1).svg" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Recompensas-->
```

CSS:

```
.recompensas-section{
   margin-top: 70px;
}
.recompensas-description {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Baloo Thambi 2', cursive;
}
.recompensas-title{
    font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Baloo Thambi 2', cursive;
  color:#160045;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}
.recompensas-img{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o flexbox no css, e crie uma nova div como no código abaixo:

```css
.recompensas-section{
   margin-top: 70px;
}
.recompensas-description {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: #333333;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: 'Baloo Thambi 2', cursive;
}
.recompensas-title{
  font-weight: 800;
  font-family: 'Baloo Thambi 2', cursive;
  color:#160045;
  letter-spacing: -1.5px;
}
/*estilo da div column*/
.column{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<section class="recompensas-section">
    <div class="row align-items-center">

        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2 class="recompensas-title">
                Ajude e ganhe recompensas
            </h2>
            
            <div class="column">                
                <p class="recompensas-description">
                    Aproveite descontos e promoções exclusivas oferecidas pelos nossos parceiros,
                    e use suas moedas para vivenciar experiências e trocar por brindes incríveis.
                </p>
                <div class="col-md-6 pull-right">
                    <img src="images/Recompensas (1).svg" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Deu certo!!! Só que a imagem ficou muito grudada com o texto, agora to tentando resolver isso kkk mas obrigada

Comment: Você pode usar no css da imagem **margin** e resolvera isso

Comment: com o margin não deu certo, só se eu estou colocando errado. mas criei uma classe da imagem, e no css coloquei .recompensas-img{
    margin-left: -50px;
}

Comment: só que ai o texto desalinha

Comment: troque o **-50px** por **50px** do margin-left

Comment: Não também... Olha como fica (está com 50px) https://prnt.sc/1wv7des

Comment: adicione na imagem **flex-direction: flex-end;**

Comment: não deu certo também kkkkk to achando que é no texto

Comment: adicionei  na classe recompensas-description **flex-direction: flex-start;** e na imagem **width: 200px; flex-direction: flex-end; margin-left: 50px;** aparentemente ta ok kkk

Comment: Não deu certo também, eu vou tentar de outro jeito essa parte, agradeço toda a ajuda!!

Comment: O problema era a coisa mais boba que vc pode imaginar!! Estava faltando fechar uma div kkkk que raivaa

Comment: Nossa, Acontece kkkk !